# Как сделать генерацию ссылок в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Тренируюсь с **Yii2 advanced**, делаю блог. Есть у меня админка и сам сайт.

В админке сделал **CRUD** управление записями блога, статьи создаются и выводятся на главной странице.
Но мне нужно сделать категории новостей и каждой новости еще отельные ссылки.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно организовать?**

Документацию **Yii2** по генерации URL я **прочитал**, но не понял суть процесса, как вижу это я:

1. В базе создаю таблицу **Categories(id, title)**, тут будут списки категорий которые я создам.
2. В таблице **News** сделать поля **(id, title, category_id)**
3. Теперь в **CRUD** при создании новости, буду выбирать категорию к которой относится данная новость и ее title будет конечной ссылкой(типа **mysite.com/category1/news1**).

*Но, как это сделать на сайте, ведь для каждой страницы нужен свой контроллер и своя views.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но, как это сделать на сайте, ведь для каждой страницы нужен свой контроллер и своя views.

Не нужно, вы просто создайте url rules в конфиге, например такой

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'news/<url:\w+>'    => 'news/news-view',
    ]
 ],
```

И у Вас по умолчанию урлы типа

```
mysite.com/news/test
```

Будут идти в контролер `News => actionNewsView` и Вы сможете брать title c get параметра

```
public function actionNewsView ()
{
    $alias = Yii::$app->request->get('url');
    $news = News::findOne(['alias' => $url, 'type' => News::TYPE_NEWS]);
    if ($news) {
        return $this->render('news-view', ['news' => $news]);
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

Если Вы хотите с категориями, то url rule нужно будет поменять немного, примерно так:

```
'category<category:[\d_\/-]+>/news-<alias:[\w]+>'=>'shop/show',

mysite.com/category1/news-test
```

Еще пару советов

- Если вы хотите строить связи между категориями и новостями, то обязательно ставьте внешние ключи при миграциях, потом при генерации CRUD, фреймворк сам добавит методы для связи между таблицами (В вашем случае many-to-one)
- Для генерации alias для url используйте [SlugBehaviour](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html), с библиотекой intl

Comment: За ответ спасибо, очень помогло.   
Но подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за символы \w+ и [\d_\/-]+ , где о них почитать?

Comment: @Fitstd
это регулярные выражения
\w - слово (alias)
\d - цифра (id)